# Change OS Language Silently (Windows 7)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, registry, windows-7-x64, regedit

I'm writing a script (powershell) for SQL Server 2014 Express Install.
The problem is: I have to change the OS Language (Region and languages) to fr_FR (French from France) Silently. The current language is fr_CA (French from Canada).

My question is: Can i change the language from intl.cpl (Region and languages) with a batch file or command line or just from the register?

Thank you

Comment: SOLVED. @Jan Chrbolka's solution will work if the HKEY LOCAL MACHINE is also edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't work for me but i found a solution to my problem.

I use a XML file to change properties by executing : 
*control.exe intl.cpl,,/f:"c:\Unattend.xml"* 
in CMD.exe as **Admin**

Here is my XML file :

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
  <gs:UserList>
    <gs:User UserID="Current"/>
  </gs:UserList>
  <!-- user locale -->
  <gs:UserLocale>
     <gs:Locale Name="fr-FR" SetAsCurrent="true" ResetAllSettings="false">            
     </gs:Locale>
  </gs:UserLocale>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

This could be as simple as one line command in PowerShell

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name "PreferredUILanguages" -Value  'fr-FR'
```

Alternatively you could use a .reg file, or batch file calling reg.exe like this

```
reg add "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" /f /v "PreferredUILanguages" /t REG_SZ /d 'fr-FR'
```

Ref: [Change OS Language using PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24450.change-os-language-using-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

To **[change windows 7 language](https://www.morphigo.com/how-to/how-to-change-windows-7-%20%20language-to-english-1338/)**
Open the Control Panel.

Snap the "View by" menu and select "Huge symbols" or "Little symbols".

Select Windows Update.

Snap the "# discretionary updates are accessible" interface

Check the container for the language you need to download.

Snap the. Install refreshes.

Come back to the Control Panel and select "District and Language".

Select the language you just introduced from the "Pick a presentation language" drop-down menu.

Snap.Apply

Change your framework area if the language isn't showing in certain projects.

You can also visit 
[url=https://www.morphigo.com/]https://www.morphigo.com/[/url]